What was the first game to feature a chicken leg as a means to restore your health?
What is the first example of a chicken leg restoring health in a computer game?
I understand Castlevania has an early example from 1986, but to be fair, it looks like roast beef or a big ham.


Wolfenstein 3D (1992) had a platter of food that featured a chicken leg https://i.sstatic.net/GPnAH0eQ.png

Gauntlet (1985) and/or Gauntlet II (1986) used plates of food as health items, and I think one of the plate images was chicken/turkey.  https://stoneagegamer.com/blog/lets-talk-turkey

Any reason this is about a chicken leg, specifically? Wouldn't "a piece of meat" be more logical, given that the specific type is a flavour added by the game designers, but the general type (i.e. meat) makes symbolic sense?

assorted rants about kids nowadays having no regards for history 'but to be fair, it looks like roast beef or a big ham...' That's because it is a pork chop

no need for rants, not everyone had the manual and I don't think it's mentioned in game.  I'm still calling it wall chicken

As hinted by a comment by John Gordon, Gauntlet I of 1985, even though Stone Age Gamer: Let's Talk Turkey says it's Gauntlet II, this video seems to show that it's I.

Especially since Gauntlet 2's Legend uses a single turkey leg on a plate instead of a plate with the turkey and other food.
